# Cómo puedo hacer esta validación en laravel?

Tags: laravel, validación

la validación es muy simple. Lo único que tiene que hacer es lo siguiente:

- Alguno de los dos campos email y phone sea obligatorio. (pueden contestar solo uno).
- Si contestan los dos debe de aplicar las validaciones para ambos campos

```
 [
    "name"=> ["required", "min:2", "max:35", "string"],
    "email"=> ["sometimes", "email:dns"],
    "phone"=> ["sometimes", "string", "min:13", "max:15"],
    "message"=> ["string", "min:6"]
 ]
```

Comment: ¿Y ese código funciona, da fallos?

Comment: Este código no hace bien la validación. Puedes dejar vacíos los dos campos. Sometimes es lo que hace solo si esta disponible aplica las validaciones.

Comment: Ok, consejo: te recomiendo ser mas claro en futuras preguntas tal vez indicar que comportamiento tiene el código

Answer (score 1):

Esa regla se cumple al usar lo siguiente `required_without`:

```
[
    "name"=> ["required", "min:2", "max:35", "string"],
    "email"=> ["required_without:phone", "email:dns"],
    "phone"=> ["required_without:email", "string", "min:13", "max:15"],
    "message"=> ["string", "min:6"]
 ]
```

El campo deberá estar presente y no ser vacío sólo cuando el otro no esté presente

Comment: `required_without:email` <-- cambiando `_` por `:`